# Why Lightning:datatable typeAttributes do not support neither tooltip nor title for url?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, datatable, lightning-datatable

I want to use `lightning:datatable` component to display list of records where the first column is the URL with `label` and `tooltip` consisting of record name and value directing to record URL in format `/{Id}`.

If I don't use `lightning:datatable`, it is quite simple

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped slds-table--cell-buffer slds-table--fixed-layout">
    <thead>
    <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
        <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Name</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="record">
        <tr>
            <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!record.Name}"><a href="{!'/' + record.Id}">{!record.Name}</a></div></td>
        </tr>
    </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, using `lightning:datatable` it seems to be impossible, even though [Lightning Datatable supports label customization](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196186/url-in-lightningdatatable), it doesn't support tooltip customization in the current Spring'18 release.

Actually [Lightning Datatable documentation suggests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm) that it uses `lightning:formattedUrl` component to format URL and [Lightning Formatted URL component documentation suggests that this component supports](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_formattedUrl.htm)  both `title` and `tooltip` attributes

> - title  String  Displays tooltip text when the mouse moves over the element.
> - tooltip    String  The text to display when the mouse hovers over the link.

However, these two attributes are not passed from Datatable, so even though I have tried this JSON

```
{
  'type': 'url',
  'typeAttributes': {
    'label': {
      'fieldName': 'Name'
    },
    'tooltip': {
      'fieldName': 'Name'
    },
    'title': {
      'fieldName': 'Name'
    }
  }
}
```

it doesn't really work since Lightning supports only `label` and `target` attributes. Is there are other hacks or workarounds to get this functionality done with Lightning Datatable?

Answer (score 4):

Tooltip customization is available in Winter '19 release. As per the documents:

This attribute for the URL type column property is new.
tooltip — Displays a tooltip for a URL in the datatable column. Use the typeAttributes property to pass the tooltip for the URL.

Eg: For assigning a particular field name to a tooltip

```
tooltip: {
    fieldName: attributeFieldName
}
```

Or for assigning a normal text to a tooltip

`tooltip:'Normal text'`